# Racing car game that finds first, second, and third place

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I found this code on youtube for a racing car game. The code is pretty simple and moves the picture box left until it hits a certain location on the form. And the first to cross the specified location is declared the winner. I would like to expand this code so I can declare a second and third place finisher. After a few weeks of trying to do this, I haven't been able to accomplish this task, apart from using a bunch of If-Then statements.

I have tried If-Then statements to accomplish this task however this is far too cumbersome and doesn't work well if you want to add more cars.

Here's my current code:

```
Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    timRace.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub timRace_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles timRace.Tick
    Randomize()

    picCar1.Left += Rnd() * 6
    picCar2.Left += Rnd() * 6
    picCar3.Left += Rnd() * 6
    picCar4.Left += Rnd() * 6

    If picCar1.Left > 600 Then
        timRace.Enabled = False
        MsgBox("Car 1 Wins")
    End If

    If picCar2.Left > 600 Then
        timRace.Enabled = False
        MsgBox("Car 2 Wins")
    End If

    If picCar3.Left > 600 Then
        timRace.Enabled = False
        MsgBox("Car 3 Wins")
    End If

    If picCar4.Left > 600 Then
        timRace.Enabled = False
        MsgBox("Car 4 Wins")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem then, can you elaborate more about what expected behaviour is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is add all the "cars" into an array and iterate that array to "move the cars" as well as get the ones in second and third places.

Here's an example using the same technique you're currently using:

```
Private Cars As PictureBox()
Private Finishers As List(Of PictureBox)

Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    ' We use the `Tag` property to store the name of the car.
    picCar1.Tag = "Car 1"
    picCar2.Tag = "Car 2"
    picCar3.Tag = "Car 3"
    picCar4.Tag = "Car 4"

    ' Add all the four cars into the array.
    Cars = {picCar1, picCar2, picCar3, picCar4}
    Finishers = New List(Of PictureBox)

    timRace.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub timRace_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timRace.Tick
    Dim remainingCars = Cars.Except(Finishers).ToArray()
    If remainingCars.Count > 0 Then
        For Each car As PictureBox In remainingCars
            Randomize()
            car.Left += Rnd() * 6
            If car.Left > 600 Then Finishers.Add(car)
        Next
    Else
        timRace.Enabled = False

        MsgBox($"{Finishers(0).Tag} Wins" & vbNewLine &
               $"{Finishers(1).Tag} finished second." & vbNewLine &
               $"{Finishers(2).Tag} finished third.")
    End If
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image: Race result]

However, I would encourage you to learn how to use the [`Random` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random) instead of using the legacy way (i.e., `Randomize` and `Rnd()`).

In which case, the code would look something like this:

```
Private Rand As New Random()

Private Sub timRace_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timRace.Tick
    Dim remainingCars = Cars.Except(Finishers).ToArray()
    If remainingCars.Count > 0 Then
        For Each car As PictureBox In remainingCars
            car.Left += Rand.Next(1, 10)
            ' ...
        Next
    Else
        ' ...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much that was exactly what I was looking for. THank you for your help!

Comment: What's with the downvote? It's a nice race. Car 4 always wins, though. Maybe it was that...

Comment: @Jimi I can't tell if you're joking or not (forgive me :D). Car 4 doesn't always win, of course. Regarding the downvote, I initially used a wrong logic (stupid mistake) so maybe it was that although I don't think so. It's not a big deal anyway. Thank you for your nice comment though :)

Comment: I was talking about the animation :)